# async promise not speeding up the execution time

Tags: javascript

I tried to parallelize each chunk to speed up the process and this is my for loop

```
  for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; m += 2) {
    fetchWorker.postMessage([nodePages, keyCountMap]);
    // console.log(m, keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap.length);
    let myRoot = nodePages[keyCountMap[m]];
    const view = await Copc.loadPointDataView(filename, copc, myRoot);
    let getters = ["X", "Y", "Z", "Intensity"].map(view.getter);
    let chunkCount = 2;
    let totalCalled = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < keyCountMap[m + 1]; j += chunkCount) {
      let remaining = keyCountMap[m + 1] - totalCalled;
      let localChunkCount = Math.min(chunkCount, remaining);
      totalCalled += localChunkCount;
      const pointTemp = new Array(localChunkCount).fill(null);
      const promises = pointTemp.map((element, index) =>
        readPoints(index + j, getters)
      );
      const done = await Promise.all(promises);
    }
  }
```

and

```
const readPoints = (id, getters) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let returnPoint = getXyzi(id, getters);
      positions.push(
        returnPoint[0] - x_min - 0.5 * width,
        returnPoint[1] - y_min - 0.5 * width,
        returnPoint[2] - z_min - 0.5 * width
      );
      const vx = (returnPoint[3] / 65535) * 255;
      color.setRGB(vx, vx, vx);
      colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
      return resolve(true);
    });
  };

  function getXyzi(index, getters) {
    return getters.map((get) => get(index));
  }
```

I think there is some error because I am not getting performance in execution time.

Can anyone please help me on figuring out what I am doing wrong?

My worker code:

[image]

Comment: Your `readPoints` method does its work synchronously, so there is no opportunity for overlapping execution.

Comment: HI @RaymondChen how can i do that ?

Comment: I added async in readPoints as async(id, getters) but still not fruitful !! can you please guide me what can i do?

Comment: async _does not mean_ parallel execution. It only means asynchronous execution. The main JS thread is literally that: a single thread. The only thing async does is work together with the scheduler to allow you to run "other code" while some normally blocking operation (like network or I/O) happens. If you need parallelism, consider using worker threads.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you for comment !! Do you mean that making multiple async call wont speed up the process?

Comment: No, all it does is run your code in such a way that the scheduler can run "something else" when it hits an `await`. That helps if you have 20 network requests that all need to run, because in async context all of those will _trigger_ sequentially in the JS side, and then the network requests happen outside of the JS engine, with the results coming in out of order. It does nothing for performance of your code if you're just "running code" that isn't blocked on anything other than itself. What it _does_ improve is browser responsiveness, because the scheduler can hold back async task execution.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for guiding me !! I started with the worker thread but i am not able to get the message passed in the worker code !! I see all people doing this in the internet !! Am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)'s got you covered.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am stuck into this !! I am not able to understand what to do for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331144/does-this-web-worker-execute-parallely

Comment: can you please share your thought on this !!

Comment: You spawn one worker _for each_ task. If you have 10 jobs, you spawn 10 workers, with the appropriate startup data. You don't "start one worker, then feed it new parameters once it's performed one task".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i am sorry i dont understand what you are suggesting !! Can you please write demo code for me in my case !! I am sorry if i am asking too much !! I am struggling on it from last three days so can you please

Comment: I can't (SO is not for tutorials, but for concrete questions and answers, and your post is not a question about web workers), but I can again recommend reading through the linked web worker tutorial on MDN. It explains everything, just don't "skip to find the right section", just start reading at the top, and then keep reading until the end.