# does this web worker execute parallely?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Hi I am learning web worker and I believe that I have managed to make it work but still, I am struggling to figure out how to make it parallel.

```
for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; m += 2) {
    fetchWorker.postMessage([keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap[m + 1]]);
 }
```

I have this for loop inside which there was another for loop and i transferred all the code into the fetchWorker.

```
import Worker from "./worker/fetcher.worker.js";
const fetchWorker = new Worker();
```

I want to parallelize this at least with 5/10 thread so can i just add fetchWorker.postMessage with different parameter one after another inside the loop and increment the variable "m" of likewise

```
for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; m += 2) {
    fetchWorker.postMessage([keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap[m + 1]]);
    fetchWorker.postMessage([keyCountMap[m+2], keyCountMap[m + 3]]);
 }
```

Does this act as two threads per loop?

This is my fetcher code:

```
import { Copc, Key } from "copc";
import * as THREE from "three";
const color = new THREE.Color();
const colors = [];
var nodePages, pages, receivedData, copc;
let x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, z_max, width;
let positions = [];
let filename = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/data.entwine.io/millsite.copc.laz";

const readPoints = (id, getters) => {
  let returnPoint = getXyzi(id, getters);
  positions.push(
    returnPoint[0] - x_min - 0.5 * width,
    returnPoint[1] - y_min - 0.5 * width,
    returnPoint[2] - z_min - 0.5 * width
  );
  const vx = (returnPoint[3] / 65535) * 255;
  color.setRGB(vx, vx, vx);
  colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
};

function getXyzi(index, getters) {
  return getters.map((get) => get(index));
}

async function load() {
  copc = await Copc.create(filename);
  let scale = copc.header.scale[0];
  [x_min, y_min, z_min, x_max, y_max, z_max] = copc.info.cube;
  width = Math.abs(x_max - x_min);
  receivedData = await Copc.loadHierarchyPage(
    filename,
    copc.info.rootHierarchyPage
  );
  nodePages = receivedData.nodes;
  pages = receivedData.pages;
  postMessage(200);
}

async function loadData(myRoot, pointCount) {
  const view = await Copc.loadPointDataView(filename, copc, myRoot);
  let getters = ["X", "Y", "Z", "Intensity"].map(view.getter);
  for (let j = 0; j < pointCount; j += 1) {
    readPoints(j, getters);
  }
  postMessage([positions, colors]);
}

load();

onmessage = function (message) {
  let mapIndex = message.data[0];
  let pointCount = message.data[1];
  console.log(mapIndex);
  let myRoot = nodePages[mapIndex];
  loadData(myRoot, pointCount);
};
```

Can anyone help me please !!

Comment: What are the workers doing? From the description of the filename `fetcher` it looks like you're trying to use web workers for something that does not need web workers.

Comment: In the worker, i am iterating number of time to get data from the data view and it is getting data from different indices so it is not very fast. The number of iteration is usually around 70,000

Comment: I have added my code of fetcher worker

Comment: You spawn one worker _for each_ task. If you have 10 jobs, you spawn 10 workers, with the appropriate startup data. You don't "start one worker, then feed it new parameters once it's performed one task". So don't create one `fetchWorker` and then have a back-and-forth with that one worker, create _pointCount_ workers, and let them do their thing. The only communication with them should be "each one giving you the result of its work when it finishes".